# Magento: Include a specific product price in a CMS block w/o customization

Tags: magento

Is there a way to include the price of a specific product in a static CMS block without writing an own Magento module?

I tried:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="1234" template="catalog/product/price.phtml"}}
```

This uses the fact that Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View loads the product from the `product_id`attribute. But this is only working if no `product` is in the registry. So on the product detail page the product of the detail page is used.

I also had a look at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product::getProduct`. This can load from a product id, but only if it is wrapped in the `product` field.

Something like

```
{{block type="catalog/product" product.product_id="1234" template="catalog/product/price.phtml"}}
```

is not working, as it will set the property `product.product_id`, not something nested like `product->product_id`.

An other option would be to add an own template file that loads the product from the productId param, but I think that is not clean.

Any cool ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not attempted to load the price in the way you suggest above before, however the immediate problem I can see is that the price.phtml file is expecting a product object, rather than just an ID.

What I'd do instead is simply make a custom .phtml file which accepts an ID from the layout and returns the desired HTML. You can then use this anywhere you like, regardless of what product is loaded by the registry or otherwise.

The key methods for your .phtml file would be:
`$id = $this->getProductId();` to load the ID from the layout, then `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);` to get the product object.

Now that you have the loaded product you can output any attributes and formatting you desire - e.g. `$product->getFinalPrice()` would give you the final sale price of the product.

Now to include your custom block, change your XML code to `{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/your/file.phtml" name="someReferenceName" product_id="1234"}}`.

The equivalent in XML is:
`<block type="core/template" template="path/to/your/file.phtml" name="someReferenceName"><action method="setProductId"><product_id>1234</product_id></action></block>`

Note: it is important to set a name for the block, because any arguments passed to the block - i.e. product_id - will be stored against this reference name. If you fail to provide a reference name, at least in the XML equivalent, your block will not receive the passed ID. I have not tested whether the same is true of the smarty-style syntax, but I expect it will be.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. I was considering this in my question already but I do not find it very clean. But the funny part is, that even the MagentoECG recommends this way: http://www.magentocommerce.com/answers/discussion/373/How-do-add-product-details-into-a-CMS-page/p1 But I think the clean way is to use a widget.

Comment: Hi Alex. Sorry, I only skimmed your question first time. Off the top of my head I can't think of a better way.. perhaps you could duplicate the price.phtml widget & modify it to load a product by given ID if an integer is passed rather than an object? Even then, the solutions are roughly equivalent - seems a lot of extra work for the same goal, unless you want the exact output of price.phtml and don't want to maintain it twice. Remember though, if the product you're loading has already been loaded elsewhere in the application it won't be re-queried, so the solution I posted is not inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension from IcebergCommerce, called Single product Embed Widget. This seems to have the feature you need, configurable to show only the product price: http://icebergcommerce.com/software/magento-product-embed-widget.html